# Search external file for specific word and store the very next word in variable in Python

Tags: python, file, search, maya

I have a file that has a line similar to this:

```
"string" "playbackOptions -min 1 -max 57 -ast 1 -aet 57
```

now i want to search the file and extract and store the value after " -aet" (in this case 57) in a variable.

I'm using

```
import mmap

with open('file.txt') as f:
    s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    if s.find('-aet') != -1:
        print('true')
```

for searching. but can't go beyond this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please check the answers to your question and consider accepting if they help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach using native string and list methods, as I usually forget regex syntax when I haven't touched it in a while:

```
tag = "-aet"  # Define what tag we're looking for.

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:  # Read file.
    for line in f:  # Loop through every line.
        line_split = line.split()  # Split line by whitespace.

        if tag in line_split and line_split[-1] != tag:  # Check if the tag exists and that it's not the last element.
            try:
                index = line_split.index(tag) + 1  # Get the tag's index and increase by one to get its value.
                value = int(line_split[index])  # Convert string to int.
            except ValueError:
                continue  # We use try/except in case the value cannot be cast to an int. This may be omitted if the data is reliable.

            print value  # Now you have the value.
```

It would be interesting to benchmark but typically regex is slower, so this may perform faster especially if the file is particularly big.

Comment: i'm noob to python, even noob to any coding, i'm from animation so much more creative than technical. but as i love coding i'm teaching myself by solving problems that i get down my production line. and thus thanks for the real help. you are genius. this 2nd option is so much easier and straightforward.

Comment: yes i tried both the method, the regex was rally slow in some case, even crashed the whole app while parsing the external file but the simple loading the file in string was way way too fast. so i went with the 2nd method. THANKS a lot guyes.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use [regular expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) to extract the values:

```py
import re

# Open the file for reading
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    # Loop through all the lines:
    for line in f:
        # Find an exact match
        # ".*" skips other options,
        # (?P<aet_value>\d+) makes a search group named "aet_value"
        # if you need other values from that line just add them here
        line_match = re.search(r"\"string\" \"playbackOptions .* -aet (?P<aet_value>\d+)", line)
        # No match, search next line
        if not line_match:
            continue
        # We know it's a number so it's safe to convert to int
        aet_value = int(line_match.group("aet_value"))
        # Do whatever you need
        print("Found aet_value: {}".format(aet_value)
```

Comment: i tried this method first, but i had speed issue with some external file parsing, it even crashed the app some time while parsing so i went with the 2nd method, i.e. loading the file in a string.

Comment: Both methods read the file in exactly the same way, line by line. Your issue is unrelated to the code.

Comment: might be. as, i have very low idea about python, i'm teaching myself bit by bit.